# YandexMaps ObjectManager и отрицательная долгота

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

ObjectManager в Яндекс. Карта не отображает нормально отрицательную долготу. Каким образом можно это исправить?

[image: Так отображается 2 точки с положительной и отрицательной долготой]

Вот [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/30m5o07wmm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectManager в Яндекс.Картах отображает точки всегда в нулевом мире, это сделано для его скорости работы с большим количеством объектов. Нулевой мир простирается от -180 до +180 градусов долготы. Если вы заходите за пределы 180 градусов влево или за пределы -180 вправо, то там точки отображаться не будут.
Если вам необходима функциональность при которой точки будут прыгать между мирами, то нужно перестать пользоваться ObjectManager. А добавлять объекты на карту обычным способом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в принципе можно решить если в Object Manager отдавать точки в пределах нулевого мира, а всё что за пределами отображать через обычные Placemark.